# Symfony 4.4. Run migrations after bundle install

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-migrations

I try to create a Bundle for Symfony 4.4 which must contain its own migrations.
How can I create doctrine migrations and enable them in the project?
Does it's possible to run `doctrine:shema:update` with bundle migrations after install the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony 4.4 there is no more bundle, it's deprecated. However, if you really need to work with bundle, look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#configuration
In your configuration:

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    # List of namespace/path pairs to search for migrations, at least one required
    migrations_paths:
        'App\Migrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/App'
        'AnotherApp\Migrations': '/path/to/other/migrations'
        'SomeBundle\Migrations': '@SomeBundle/Migrations'
```